# Using distinct or group by?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is how my table looks like:

[image]

Now i have this query for suggestion:

```
  $data = Districts::distinct()->whereRaw('LOWER(district) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->orWhereRaw('LOWER(region) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->select('region', 'district')->get();
```

What i want is that if user enter for example: Kreis 2 to get only one record Kreis 2, in my case it get few of them because Kreis 2 have 3 regions. Any suggestion how can do that?

Comment: Distinct would work correctly this way if you have only district in your select: `->select('district')->get();`.

Comment: but what about regions then?

Comment: If you need to select regions too you should use group by instead of distinct.

Comment: when i use group by i dont get anything

Comment: group by what? how query should looks like?

Comment: Actually if you group them you will still have the same result because each "Kreis" has many regions, so if you get one record for each "Kreis" it won't be correct, because it will shown only one of the regions that this "Kreis" has.

Comment: ok so what do u suggest then ?

Comment: Leave at like this, this is the only way to correctly show a district and a region. You can show unique district, but if you want to show district and regions then you will have some "Kreis" which are the same name but have different regions.